# capturar html de uma página externa pegar dados da tabela e enviar via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Seguinte, como posso capturar o html puro de uma página, por exemplo `"site.com.br/tabela_precos"` esse site tem um retorno basicamente assim:

```
<html> ....
arquivos e configurações javascript ....
outras tags html ..... 
......
```

e aqui uma tabela

```
<h2 id="tabela_titulo">Título</h2>
    <table id="tabela_info">

<tr>
   <td>Dado da tabela</td>
</tr>
```

os `<tr> e <td>` estão sem id/class, a ideia seria fazer um loop com eles, como seguem um padrão não terá problemas...

e após pegar esses valores, gostaria de envia-los via Ajax para um arquivo PHP

Comment: Você tem acesso a esse PHP? Se sim, por quê não obter os dados da tabela direto com o PHP?

Comment: Achei que seria mais rápido/fácil com javascript já que ele poda acessar o DOM.

Comment: Ele pode acessar o DOM da sua página de forma fácil. De página externa, o PHP faz de maneira semelhante e você economiza uma requisição. Basta você obter o código HTML desta página e analisá-lo com a classe [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Não sabia disso, muito obrigado, vou dar uma olhada